# C# Drag and Drop picturebox 2

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem. I have a group of picturebox to be dragged into one picturebox. How to disable a specific picturebox after being dragged?? So, it can't be dragged anymore.

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
      pictureBox1.DoDragDrop(pictureBox1.Image, DragDropEffects.All);
  }

  private void pictureBox2_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
      e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    else
      e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
  }

  private void pictureBox2_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
  {
    if ((e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap)))
      this.pictureBox2.Image = (Bitmap)(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap));
  }
```

Comment: Use a flag, maybe in the Tag of the PB to allow/disallow dragging! Test it in the `pictureBox1_MouseDown` set it in the/each `_DragDrop` event!

Comment: @TaW my thoughts exactly :-)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dragging the `PictureBox`'s Image, drag the `PictureBox`.
When dropped, set it's Tag property to `true`.

In the `MouseDown` event, check if the Tag property is null, and drag only if it is.

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && pictureBox1.Tag == null)
        pictureBox1.DoDragDrop(pictureBox1.Image, DragDropEffects.All);
}

private void pictureBox2_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(PictureBox)))
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    else
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
}

private void pictureBox2_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(PictureBox)))
    {
        var picturebox = ((PictureBox)e.Data.GetData(typeof(PictureBox)));
        picturebox.Tag = true;
        this.pictureBox2.Image = picturebox.Image;
    }
}
```